# tinyMCE3.2 giving problems in IE 7

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have replaced tinyMCE2.x to tinyMCE3.2 and its currently giving errors in IE7 one of the prominent error is on click of any link it says "Are you sure you want to Navigate away from this page" this is major and wastes all the effort of replacement. Somebody please help.